# How to install vizdoom using Google Colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/simoninithomas/Deep_reinforcement_learning_Course/blob/master/Policy%20Gradients/Doom/Doom%20REINFORCE%20Monte%20Carlo%20Policy%20gradients.ipynb) using Google Colab. But I have problems with running `from vizdoom import *` that should enable the Doom environment.
I tried to execute `!pip install vizdoom`, but it failed.

```
Collecting vizdoom
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/15/8053139ab32054bed0b1bf46473f54c5a8d85e5c1d25b23410bc5de913c1/vizdoom-1.1.4.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from vizdoom) (1.14.3)
Building wheels for collected packages: vizdoom
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for vizdoom ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-GsCBh9/vizdoom/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-tsUxvp --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for vizdoom
  Running setup.py clean for vizdoom
Failed to build vizdoom
Installing collected packages: vizdoom
  Running setup.py install for vizdoom ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-GsCBh9/vizdoom/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-N3TTEU/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-GsCBh9/vizdoom/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-N3TTEU/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-GsCBh9/vizdoom/
```

The instruction indicate that "You need to download vizdoom and place the folder in the repos". But it's unclear to me how to do it in Google Colab.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show pip install error message

Comment: @cricket_007: Please see the updated post.

Comment: That should work fine... https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/adding-libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll first need to install the vizdoom deps for Linux. They are listed on this page:
https://github.com/mwydmuch/ViZDoom/blob/master/doc/Building.md#-linux

```
%%bash
# Install deps from 
# https://github.com/mwydmuch/ViZDoom/blob/master/doc/Building.md#-linux

apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libsdl2-dev libjpeg-dev \
nasm tar libbz2-dev libgtk2.0-dev cmake git libfluidsynth-dev libgme-dev \
libopenal-dev timidity libwildmidi-dev unzip

# Boost libraries
apt-get install libboost-all-dev

# Lua binding dependencies
apt-get install liblua5.1-dev
```

After installing these, I was able to import all the libraries successfully:

```
import tensorflow as tf      # Deep Learning library
import numpy as np           # Handle matrices
from vizdoom import *        # Doom Environment
import random                # Handling random number generation
import time                  # Handling time calculation
from skimage import transform# Help us to preprocess the frames

from collections import deque# Ordered collection with ends
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # Display graphs
```

Here's a full example notebook:
**https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zDRkLhgjfOzW9C8jCtQ7-99TPDhxpCev**

The install takes ~10 minutes. You may want to consider using Colab with [a local Jupyter runtime](http://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) so that you can skip the setup overhead on subsequent invocations of your notebook.

Answer (score 2):

In case you face the following error

```
Collecting vizdoom
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2d/6c/23565c09387173423883e7881fce53541ff89b5209ca0904c67e577dd6ac/vizdoom-1.1.7.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from vizdoom) (1.16.4)
Building wheels for collected packages: vizdoom
  Building wheel for vizdoom (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for vizdoom
  Running setup.py clean for vizdoom
Failed to build vizdoom
Installing collected packages: vizdoom
  Running setup.py install for vizdoom ... error
ERROR: Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-4cphk6e9/vizdoom/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-u_ywx8n5/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-4cphk6e9/vizdoom/
```

Simply run **apt-get update** before installing dependencies:

```
%%bash
# Install deps from 
# https://github.com/mwydmuch/ViZDoom/blob/master/doc/Building.md#-linux

apt-get update

apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libsdl2-dev libjpeg-dev \
nasm tar libbz2-dev libgtk2.0-dev cmake git libfluidsynth-dev libgme-dev \
libopenal-dev timidity libwildmidi-dev unzip

# Boost libraries
apt-get install libboost-all-dev

# Lua binding dependencies
apt-get install liblua5.1-dev
```