# Cannot install python-weka-wrapper/javabridge on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install the python-weka-wrapper on Google Colab using

```
!pip install python-weka-wrapper
```

And I am seeing the following output:

```
Collecting python-weka-wrapper
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2a/41/19c7bc2e177371cc273cc8aa17d66bd3ef9a6192160eecc56566ea31d959/python-weka-wrapper-0.3.15.tar.gz
Collecting javabridge>=1.0.14 (from python-weka-wrapper)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a6/a0/c59bccabed99b1d4ac68166c59c679b375bfca75b78688b52c541b711578/javabridge-1.0.18.tar.gz
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-24j9c0j5/javabridge/
```

I have successfully checked/installed all Python packages needed:

- numpy
- pillow
- matplotlib
- pygraphviz

Comment: python-weka-wrapper still requires a JVM to be available for running Weka. It uses the javabridge library for communicating with the JVM. In order to compile that library, you need to have a JDK installed (requires its header files for compiling). It seems to be possible to install underlying libraries according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50667565/how-to-install-vizdoom-using-google-colab#50669525). Disclaimer: never used Google's colaboratory.

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same error. Error is due to javabridge (a dependency) installation failing. In my case the error was due to the fact that I did not have JDK installed **on my Google Colab Runtime**.

**Note: Even though JDK folders might be present in your machine (and similarly in Google Colab), doesn't necessarily mean that javac is present or works. Usually most machines have JRE running even though the JDK folders might seem to be present in the */usr/lib/jvm/* directory. That's what confounded me for a long time. So you have to apt install openjdk .**

So, after installing openjdk properly and setting the JAVA_HOME properly, javabridge and python-weka-wrapper3 smoothly installed.

I'm summarizing all the commands I used to install **python-weka-wrapper3** on **Google Colab**

```
import os
import sys
sys.path
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/")
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/"
!apt-get install build-essential python3-dev
!apt-get install python3-pil python3-pygraphviz
!apt install openjdk-11-jdk
!pip3 install javabridge --no-cache-dir
!pip3 install python-weka-wrapper3 --no-cache-dir

import weka.core.jvm as jvm
jvm.start()
```

So, I hope this helps! Feel free to ask me any more questions related to this.

Also note while trying to rectify the issue, I came across some posts stating Oracle JDK might be necessary. Complete nonsense. weka-wrapper3 works just fine with openjdk.

The comments from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756910/cant-pip-install-javabridge) question helped me in understand the issue to resolve the error when I faced it.